# Как вывести вложенное меню в шаблоне django

Tags: django

Помогите нубу. суть вопроса в том, что необходимо вывести вложенное меню на шаблоне.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:ProductListByCategory', args=[self.slug])
```

index.html

```
   <ul>
       {% for category in categories %}

           {% if category.parent %}
            <li><a href="#">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
               {% else %}
               <li><a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
           {% endif %}


       {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение *в лоб* родными средствами Django - рекурсивный квадратичный алгоритм, который завалит вашу СУБД запросами, ототжрёт кучу ресурсов и может привести к переполнению стека:

**index.html**

```
<ul>
  {% for node in root_categories %}
    {% include "menu.html" %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**menu.html**

```
<li><a href="{{ node.get_absolute_url }}">{{ node.name }}</a>
  {% if node.child.count %}
    <ul>
      {% for child in node.child %}
        {% with node=child %}
          {% include "menu.html" %}
        {% endwith %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
</li>
```

Правильный подход для работы в Django с древовидными структурами - это использовать [django-mptt](https://pypi.org/project/django-mptt/) или [django-treebeard](https://pypi.org/project/django-treebeard/).